# Using a Matlab tracking algorithm from Java

Tags: java, matlab, sensor-fusion

I am trying to use one of Matlab's trackingalgorithms from a Java code. I am having trouble with the Library Compiler. When I try to use a persistent variable, it gives me an error:

**Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-0.**

The function I want to generate the Java Library from:

```
function tracks = vfusion(detections,time) 
    persistent tracker;
    if isempty(tracker)
          tracker = trackerGNN( ...
              'TrackerIndex', 0, ...
              'FilterInitializationFcn', @initcvkf, ...
              'Assignment', 'MatchPairs', ...
              'AssignmentThreshold', 15*[1 Inf], ...
              'TrackLogic', 'History', ...  % History|Score
              'ConfirmationThreshold', [2 3], ...
              'DeletionThreshold', [5 5], ...
              'DetectionProbability', 0.9, ...
              'FalseAlarmRate', 1e-6, ...
              'Beta', 1, ...
              'Volume', 1, ...
              'MaxNumTracks', 100, ...
              'MaxNumSensors', 20, ...
              'StateParameters', struct(), ...
              'HasDetectableTrackIDsInput', false, ...
              'HasCostMatrixInput', false ...
              );
    end    
    d = { ...
        objectDetection( ...
            time, ...  % Time
            detections(1).measurement, ...  % Measurement
            'MeasurementNoise', [1.0,0.0,0.0;0.0,1.0,0.0;0.0,0.0,1.0], ...
            'SensorIndex', uint32(1), ...
            'ObjectClassID', detections(1).objectClassId, ...
            'MeasurementParameters', struct(), ...  % sensor frame transformation
            'ObjectAttributes', struct('valid', true) ...
        ), ...
        objectDetection( ...
            time, ...  % Timetracks
            detections(2).measurement, ...  % Measurement
            'MeasurementNoise', [1.0,0.0,0.0;0.0,1.0,0.0;0.0,0.0,1.0], ...
            'SensorIndex', uint32(1), ...
            'ObjectClassID', detections(2).objectClassId, ...
            'MeasurementParameters', struct(), ...  % sensor frame transformation
            'ObjectAttributes', struct('valid', false) ...
        ), ...
        objectDetection( ...
            time, ...  % Time
            detections(3).measurement, ...  % Measurement
            'MeasurementNoise', [1.0,0.0,0.0;0.0,1.0,0.0;0.0,0.0,1.0], ...
            'SensorIndex', uint32(2), ...
            'ObjectClassID',detections(3).objectClassId, ...
            'MeasurementParameters', struct(), ...  % sensor frame transformation
            'ObjectAttributes', struct('valid', true) ...
        ) ...
    };
    [confirmedTracks] = tracker(d, time);
    for i = 1:length(confirmedTracks)
        tracks(i).State = confirmedTracks(i).State;
    end

end
```

And the example script:

```
time = 43.0;
d0.measurement = [0.2, 0.0, 0.3];
d1.measurement = [1.2, 2.0, 3.3];
d2.measurement = [1.4, 2.5, 3.1];

d0.objectClassId = uint32(10);
d1.objectClassId = uint32(10);
d2.objectClassId = uint32(10);

detections = [d0, d1, d2];

for i = 1:100
    time = (time+i/10.0)
    tracks = vfusion(detections, time);
end
```

Anyone have any ideas? Have you used persistent variables with this Library Compiler?

Comment: You gave us part of the error but not all of it. It will tell you the exact line number where it's occurring. We also don't have line numbers here, so can you please post the code snippet that happens to be at whatever line is throwing your error? If you're using the code wrap `...` please include all the subsequent lines up to the `;`.